# Check whether a folder exists in a path in c#?

Tags: c#, directory

How to check whether a folder named `RM` exists inside a directory...I have given the directory path through textbox like `txtBoxInput.Text` and in this path i have to check...Any suggestion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Path.Combine and Directory.Exists ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx

```
if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(txtBoxInput.Text, "RM"))
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: Just as questions should be questions, answers should be answers (e.g., sans ?), lest they be read as sarcasm.

Comment: It's a question because I wasn't entirely sure I was understanding the question correctly. In the same way in a real world conversation I would say "could you use X?". Not sarcasm at all - just English.

Comment: Sure sounded like sarcasm though.

Comment: @StevenRobbins can you tell me how to check the shared folder in local pc exist.I need to test it from pocket pc.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Directory.Exists()` to test whether a folder exists at a particular moment in time, but use it with caution!  If you do something like:

```
if (Directory.Exists(path))
{
    // Uh-oh!  Race condition here!
    // Do something in path
}
```

you've fallen into a classic blunder.  It's entirely possible that, between the `Directory.Exists()` call and the `// Do something in path`, a user will have deleted the directory.  No matter what, *whenever* you do file I/O, you *must* handle the exceptions that get thrown if something isn't accessible, doesn't exist, etc.  And if you have to handle all the errors anyway, it frequently isn't worth the effort to put an additional, superfluous check at the top.

Comment: having the directory deleted after you've detected it is the raison d'etre for exceptions. Of course I can understand someone's confusion if they use exceptions for any and every error.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;


if (Directory.Exists(path))
{
     // Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Don't do this unless you still properly handle failures to open/read the file.  If you fail to handle failures, you've created a race condition and, potentially, a security flaw.

Comment: The original question asked how to check if a DIRECTORY exists. Thats exactly what the code does. What POSSIBLE open/read files failures handles could I put in here?

Comment: @Greg_D Nobody said it's a commercial code, there may not even be any failure handling (study purposes, maybe?). Besides, the answer is neither wrong, nor misleading, only incomplete in your concept.. then it shouldn't be downvoted.

Comment: @MarceloRamires:  What makes you think I downvoted this answer?  (I didn't.)  Either way, a race condition is a race condition and any developer should go into that scenario with eyes wide open.  If the race condition exists, it should be a conscious choice, not a blunder from a position of ignorance.

Comment: @Felipe:  Anything done via the tested path inside the conditional could fail explosively, or at least throw an exception triggered by the path not existing.  If `// Do your stuff` is still handling all the `DirectoryNotFoundException` (or whatever), great.  But if this existence test is trying to avoid handling those exceptions, then it's failed.

Comment: @Greg_D: The existence test was not mean't to avoid handling those exceptions. The existence test was written to answer the original question. The question did not mention tips on security, or handling exceptions. It wanted a way to check if a directory existed, and that's exaclty what I answered. Also, USUALLY when a question is downvoted, and it only has one comment, well... you know what we think.

Comment: @MarceloRamires:  A race condition is always an error, especially when it's so trivially simple to get right.  If this is code for study, it's _especially_ important that issues like this be brought up because if they aren't, the subject is learning the wrong way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

String Path=txtBoxInput.Text+'//'+"RM";

```
 if (Directory.Exists(path))
return true;
```