# get the value of notepad and put it inside the c# string?

Tags: c#, file, notepad

Notepad:

```
Hello world!
```

How I'll put it in C# and convert it into string..?

So far, I'm getting the path of the notepad.

```
 string notepad = @"c:\oasis\B1.text"; //this must be Hello world
```

Please advice me.. I'm not familiar on this.. tnx

Comment: Are you asking how to READ a file CREATED in notepad?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can read text using the `File.ReadAllText()` method:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        string path = @"c:\oasis\B1.txt";

        try {

            // Open the file to read from.
            string readText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
            Console.WriteLine(readText);

        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            // Handle file not found.  
        }

    }
```

Comment: This isn't correct, you have a race condition between your call to File.Exists and actually reading the file.  If the file is deleted in that period, your solution will crash.

Comment: @Greg D, that's a bit nitpicky, don't you think?  Is there anything about this question that makes you think the code needs to be that bullet proof?

Comment: @Greg D, on second thought, I stumbled onto [your answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509415/check-whether-a-folder-exists-in-a-path-in-c/4509517#4509517) and like that a lot.  Thanks!  I've updated my answer.  (I still disagree with the downvote though :)

Comment: In cases like this, yes, the code should be that bullet proof.  Especially because it's so easy to be so, and that nit-pick could easily be a security vulnerability in your codebase.  :)

Answer (score 6):

You need to read the content of the file, e.g.:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Or, as simply as possible:

```
return File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Answer (score 5):

make use of StreamReader and read the file as shown below

```
string notepad = @"c:\oasis\B1.text";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(notepad)) 
            {
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
                {
                    sb.Append(sr.ReadLine());
                }
            }

string s = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx)

```
string text_in_file = File.ReadAllText(notepad);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Reading From a Text File (Visual C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287534%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), in this example `@` is not used when `StreamReader` is being called, however when you write the code in Visual Studio it will give the below error for each `\`

> Unrecognized escape sequence

To escape this error you can write `@` before `"` that is at the beginning of your path string.
I shoul also mentioned that it does not give this error if we use `\\` even if we do not write `@`.

```
// Read the file as one string.
System.IO.StreamReader myFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\oasis\B1.text");
string myString = myFile.ReadToEnd();

myFile.Close();

// Display the file contents.
Console.WriteLine(myString);
// Suspend the screen.
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3):

check this example:

```
// Read the file as one string.
System.IO.StreamReader myFile =
   new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
string myString = myFile.ReadToEnd();

myFile.Close();

// Display the file contents.
Console.WriteLine(myString);
// Suspend the screen.
Console.ReadLine();
```