# Error at checking if directory exists | compiler says directory not found

Tags: c#, path, exists

I wanted to make a short programme which looks if a specific directory exists.
If not, it should look for the second directory. If it doesn't exist like the first one, it should look for the third directory, and so on.

[Here's](http://pastebin.com/GbKHvLbP) the code.

The compiler says at starting the program: A part of the path "C:\Program Files\GameforgeLive" couldn't be found.

But the program should skip that path if it doesn't exist.

Do you have any advices?

My check-if-directory-exists-method:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(newclientgame))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.Delete(newclientgame, true);
    }
    else
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Wait..");

    }
```

Comment: The *compiler* gives you that error?

Answer (score 1):

If you wouldn't mind, copy paste some of the code into the question.  But I would suggest (since I won't click the link to look at, I'm not sure if you're doing this already), that you use:

```
if(!Directory.Exists("your path")
```

Post your code here and I can maybe provide a better solution if this is what you are already using.  Also this post describes another user with this problem.  [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509415/check-whether-a-folder-exists-in-a-path-in-c)

EDIT...

```
if (!Directory.Exists(newclientgame))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.Delete(newclientgame, true);
    }
```

This **if** statement says, if the directory specified by the path "newclientgame" does not exist, then I should delete it.  Are you sure this is the functionality you want? It might be too late for me to be thinking logically but I feel you have it backwards.  I think you want.

```
if(Directory.Exists(newclientgame))
{
    // delete directory
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to delete the directory when it doesn't exists?

Comment: No I don't want to delete a directory if it doesn't exist. I want to check if the directory exist, if it exists -> delete

Comment: Thanks a lot! a little exclamation mark.. I removed the "!" and now it works

Comment: To explain, the '!' means NOT, or false in your case.  Please mark this as the answer if you don't mind so others will know if they enter the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
@"C:\Program Files\GameforgeLive";

```
Instead of C:\\ use C:\
```

Comment: A part of the path "C:\Program Files\GameforgeLive" couldn't be found.